# What's the industry standard way to organize Visual Studio projects and code for .NET Cross-platform development

Tags: .net, visual-studio, mono, cross-platform, projects-and-solutions

I have a rather large solution of C# projects in Visual Studio. I want to port some of those projects to work in MONO and to run say on a MAC. Of course some things don't work and some things I don't want to port because they are not applicable on a MAC.

One approach is Solution and Project Configurations. This allows me to exclude projects I don't want to build (unfortunately Visual Studio does not make that easily visible but anyway...).

The second approach which could work in tandem with the first is to use pre compiler directives such as #if MONO and then do something at that point. This is good but then it creates multiple versions of the same assembly. How do I distinguish the two from each other post compile? Is this a problem?

Even if the top two approach work, sometimes I want part of a large project. I don't want to go through 20 or so files and put #if MONO do I? I can highjack the project file by hand but there is no visibility on that whatsoever in visual studio. No one else on the team can tell what's going on unless they unload the project and open the XML and take a look. This sounds quite crazy. To make things worse, sometimes the project references something and I want to exclude the reference for MONO. Now I have to edit the csproj.

I can split the project, but what if at some point I want to port to yet another platform. The intersections of which platform needs what code can get crazy. To make things worse, I can have projects referencing this large project which may then also have to split. This all works but it will cause project overload won't it?

I can't find a good clean solution. Any tips? Is there a standard for this I can follow. If VS had more visibility into the edits of the csproj file, this might work.

Comment: FWIW: I had a similar issue to implement a library for both WPF and Silverlight: in the code I simply used some #if to select a branch depending of the platform (often differing parameters); for the references I created some "proxy" projects, one for each implementation that were just useful to reference the right version of the library (this was based on the current build configuration WPF/SILVERLIGHT); I factored the common code in dedicated projects suffixed with ".Common". In the end this was quite clean and usable, you just had to remember to add new code in ".Common" projects.

Comment: Could you give some concrete examples of things that work on a platform and not on the other?

Comment: There are many different kinds of examples. The one that's the most frustrating is when you have a large project and you only want to compile half of it in MONO for MAC OSX and not the rest (because you don't need the rest and because it wouldn't compile even if you needed it). I could split it into two projects but what if I had yet another platform (say MAC Linux), which happens to have some things in common with windows and other things in common with MAC. Now what?

Comment: For project builds you should be able to manage it with the "Configuration Manager": you create a configuration for each platform and you select only the projects you want to build.

Comment: Yet but what about a single project, if I want half the code in that project?

Comment: You create a new project and you link only the files you need: you do "add existing item" -> "add as link" (instead of "add": change the value in the drop-down). Or you create a project common, on which both depends, other projects for the targets that reference the common one, and add their custom code.

Answer (score 3):

You could also set up a folder structure and split your solution into a common solution which contains platform-independent projects and platform-specific solutions which contain platform-specific projects.

So for example an application.sln containing all your common projects and for the sake of argument we also have a iOS and Android solution.

- root folder

  - application (folder)
  - application.Droid (folder)
  - application.Ios (folder)
  - application.sln
  - application.Droid.sln
  - application.Ios.sln

Within the platform-specific solutions you could reference to the common projects by adding for example a '[application]' folder with additional common project sub-folders to your platform-specific projects. Successively adding all required common files as links.

The above answer is one of the possibilities you could also:

- Create a portable class library which you share among platform specific projects
- Use MvvmCross ([MvvmCross GitHub](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross)) so you have a core project which you can reference in your platform specific projects

Answer (score 2):

This is a well known programming problem, if solution exists they usually require some work and even more when a project is not designed from scratch to be portable. As you correctly pointed out, pre processed statement will quickly become an overhead and a real pain to maintain and expand over time.

Yet it is not easy to answer this question directly since the solution you are seeking might be highly dependent of your implementation. Generally speaking I would advise you to make extensive use of well known design pattern such as [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern), [Bridge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern), [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern), etc.

As an exmaple, start by identifying every single piece of code which is platform dependent, define API interfaces responsible to handle these specificities in your core project and implement them into dedicated projects - usually one per platform. Once that's done, go back to your core project and define an interface which will contains factory methods to instantiate these specific classes. Again implements specific factories in their respective projects.

At this point you can decide at runtime which backend you wish to use by selecting the factory who will instantiate your classes. The next step would be to provide some plugable system to load the desired factory at runtime, thanks to the reflection this part is probably the easiest one. You go though every assemblies contained in a special folder, analyse their types to detect if they implement your factory interfaces and if they do : load them.

Comment: While your answer is interesting when the issue is at the programming level IMHO what the OP needs is more a way of managing the projects items (sln, csproj, references...) more than the code itself because Mono and Microsoft implementation are really close ... but I may be wrong.

Comment: @Pragmateek Well please accept my apologies if I am off topic. I may have misunderstood the question. :(

Comment: No I think you've correctly understood the question :) but if the situation is alike the one I describe in my comment there is no need for such sophisticated patterns. But I may be wrong and it's why I've requested some concrete examples to work with. :)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, keep projects in a solution small and concise; platform-dependent bits should ideally be implemented in separate projects altogether. You might want to look at software creational design methods like the Abstract factory pattern to keep platform-specific dependencies low, clustered and in check.

On an abstract level, one approach to monitor development is to use Team Foundation Server (TFS). It basically provides git functionality for Visual Studio development, so you can easily track csproj. If you have a team working on Java or Android etc via Eclipse you can use TFS via the TFS plugin to keep everybody on the same page and to keep track of changes and revisions in the projects and in your overall solution.

Normally projects with potentially multiplatform implementations are structured from the ground up this way, right from the envisioning and planning stage. If you are stuck with a project that you now want to port, you could use the first two options you suggested, and if differentiating the assemblies is a problem, there are multiple third-party decompilers that can do the job for you.

Hope that helps.

Comment: what does Java have to do with .csproj files? downvoting

Comment: Apologies. I corrected the answer, I meant that project changes for Java development teams can also be tracked via TFS. I must have overlooked the meaning of the answer as I added that bit to it.